# How to adjust the horizontal placement of x-axis-labels in ggplot2 (for a continuous x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have created a graph using ggplot2 with a continuous scale on the x-axis. I'm trying to label the endpoints of the axis with two rather long labels. Therefore, I want the label at x=1 to be left-justified and the label at x=10 to be right-justified (otherwise they are cut off).

I already found out that I could use hjust in axis.text.x if my scale was discrete but, unfortunately, it's continuous. So now I'm looking for something similar to place the left label at hjust=0 (or 0.1) and the right label at hjust=1 (or 0.9).

This is a simplified example of the code I'm using.

```
set1<-data.frame(gr=c("group 1", "group 2", "group 3"),
             sat=c(7.6, 9.5, 2.2))

ggplot(set1, aes(sat, gr))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10,
                 labels=paste0(c("very dissatisfied", "", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "", "very satisfied")),
                 limits=c(1,10))+
  geom_point(size=2, colour="black")
```

I want "very dissatisified" to start parallel to the y-axis and "very satisfied" to end parallel to the end of the graph.

Comment: Add `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=c(0, 1)))`